# Ayuda urgente con problema en c++

Tags: c++

El enunciado es el siguiente:

En un arreglo unidimensional se ha almacenado el número total de toneladas de cereales cosechadas durante cada mes del año anterior. Construya un algoritmo que proporcione la siguiente información:

1. El promedio anual de toneladas cosechadas
2. ¿Cuántos meses tuvieron una cosecha superior al promedio anual?
3. ¿Cuántos meses tuvieron una cosecha inferior al promedio anual?
4. ¿Cuál fue el mes en el que se produjeron mayor número de toneladas?

Ya hice el código que me permite responder las interrogantes B y C pero no se como resolver las interrogantes A y D. A qui dejo lo que tengo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main(){ 

int cos[12],c=0,conta=0,canta2=0; 

float total=0;


for(int i=0; i<12; i++){ 

cout<<"Ingresa el mes "<<i+1<<" cantidad de cosecha : ";

cin>>cos[i]; 

c=c+cos[i];

}

total= c/12;

cout<<"PROMEDIO ES : "<<total <<endl;

for(int i=0; i<12;i++){ 

if(cos[i]>total){  

conta++; 

} 

else{ 

 canta2++; 

}

}

cout<<" Mayores  : "<<conta<<endl;

cout<<"Menores :  "<<canta2 <<endl;

getch();

}
```

Comment: Suma los elementos del array entre si, y luego divides el total entre 12. Consigue el mayor elemento del array.

Comment: No entiendo cómo con ese código dices que ya pudiste resolver el inciso b pero no el a, cuando el indico b depende de tu respuesta al inciso a

Comment: Como es eso que puedes hacer los 2 que dependen del promedio, y dices que que en el que te pide el promedio no lo puedes hacer?

Comment: Por favor edita el título de tu pregunta, poner *Ayuda* y *Urgente* no hará que recibas respuestas más rápido. Un título más descriptivo si que llamará la atención a tu pregunta. Un título más coherente sería *Calcular la media aritmética (promedio) y el máximo valor de una lista de  valores en C++*. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Este es el codigo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr int size = 12;

// Para el A. Sumas todos y lo divides dentro del tamaño
int promedio(const int cos[size]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        sum += cos[i];
    }
    return sum/size;
}

// Para el D. Vas comparando uno a uno, siempre quedandote
// con el mas grande
int maximo(const int cos[size]) {
    int max = cos[0];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        max = std::max(max, cos[i]);
    }
    return max;
}
```